# Saving CEWP Settings

Tags: sharepoint, settings, save, appearance, cewp

I have been working with CEWP for a few weeks now, and I have not ahd this problem until today. I want to cahnge the chrome type settings, but it doesn't save the changes for me. Like I said, I haven't had this problem until just now. Does anyone know how I might be able to fis this?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is JavaScript is erroring out on page load, and this is causing your web part not to save the settings.  For clarity, is it only the appearance chrome settings that is not saving.  Can you change the web part title?

Use IE9+ and press F12 to show the developer toolbar.  Click on the Console tab after the page loads, when you edit the web part, you're looking for JavaScript errors that may prevent your WP from saving the dialog after changes.  Chrome and Firefox's Firebug plugin can do the same thing.

Start there, and we can troubleshoot further if I'm wrong.